# list item classes?

Tags: html, css

Ok, so i have an unordered list with a background applied to it. 
I also have list items with classes so 
i can specify the width of each one individually.

Why can i not see the changes like width i added to the classes on each list?
although i do see it in Dreamweaver design view.

```
<ul id="graph">
<li class="1"><span>HTML</span></li>
<li class="2"><span>CSS</span></li>
<li class="3"><span>Javascript</span></li>
<li class="4"><span>SEO</span></li>
<li class="5"><span>Photoshop</span></li>
</ul>

#graph li {
 list-style-type: none;
 display: block;
 background-image: url(../img/graph_bg.gif);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 margin-top: 20px;
}

#graph li .1 {
 height: 35px;
 display: block;
 width: 85%;
}
```

etc , etc

Comment: ".1"? As an aside, possibly, IDs/class-names are not allowed to start with digits if I remember correctly. Basically they should follow this regex: `-?[_a-zA-Z]+[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*`

Comment: Thanks, i suspected that was the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that `1`, etc are not valid class names. I suspect they need to start with a letter.

Edit: on an unrelated note, is there any reason why you have `<span>` tags inside the `<li>` tags?

Comment: cause i'm controlling text with them

Comment: @tom: Ok, fair enough. If my solution helped, don't forget to click on that check mark to accept it :)